# Paypal send money from website

Tags: paypal

on paypals page, you can click on 'send money' enter the email address and $$amount and hit send... and then paypal asks for login etc...

what I want to know, is there a way, I can essentially submit that form with the email address and $$ already populated

something like paypal.com/sendmoney?to_email=xyz@xyz.com&&amount=25.00

I want to be able to provide my users with a link that already contains the info so they dont have to click the link and then fill in the details when they get to the page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that directly with the PayPal page, but you could build your own version of that page using the [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), specifically [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).